Revisiting proof that all bases of a free module $M$ over a commutative unitary ring are equipotent
I am following closely the book of T.S. Blyth, Module Theory. There is a theorem which says that every free $R$-module $M$ where $R$ is a commutative unitary ring, has equipotant base.
The process is a follows: We take a maximal ideal in $R$ and produce $IM$ which is essentially all finite linear combinations of elements in $M$ with coefficients from $I$. This is a submodule of $M$. It can also be shown that $M/IM$ is a vector space over $R/I$.
Next, we take a basis of $M$, $\{x_j|j\in J\}$. If we map the bases by $x_j\mapsto x_j+IM$. They claim that this mapping is injective, since if $x_j+IM=x_k+IM$, with $x_j\neq x_k$, then having $x_j-x_k\in IM$, is impossible. This is due to the fact that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ which does not contain $1_R$. My question is, how does this bolded sentence explains the fact that $x_j-x_k\in IM$ cannot happen?

All elements from $M$ have unique representations as finite linear combinations of $x_j$'s. And $$IM = \{\sum_{j\in J} a_jx_j : a_j\in I\}$$
But the nonzero coefficients of $x_j-x_k$ are $1_R, -1_R\not\in I$.

so simple, thank you!!
